# android-studioタグを使い過ぎではないか？

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方, タグ

[android-studio](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio)タグの使い方はどうでしょうか。自分の印象だと、何でもかんでも[android-studio](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio)がついている印象があります。<sup>IDEはこれを使ってるよ！という表明のつもりなのかもしれませんが…</sup>

私は、**Android Studioやそれに関連するツールについて質問する時に使うタグであって、コーティングについて質問する時に使うタグではない**と思っています。

皆さんはどう思われますでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

私の考えを述べておきます。

> Android Studioやそれに関連するツールについて質問する時に使うタグであって、コーティングについて質問する時に使うタグではないと思っています。

この考えに行き着いた理由は以下の通りです:

### 1.本家SOのタグ抜枠

本家SOでは以下のようになっています。

> Use for questions about using Android Studio, an official IDE targeted at Android development. Do NOT use for questions about programming for Android in general; instead use [android].

Androidの開発向けの公式IDE、Android Studioを使うことについての質問に使ってください。Androidのプログラミングについての質問には**使用しないでください**。その代わりに[android]タグを使ってください。

本家SOに従えと言うわけではありませんが、ここに書いてあることは最もだと思います。

### 2.もしコーティングについて許容したら

コーティングについての質問を許容してしまったら[android](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)*はいらなくなる*と思います。**質問内容が[android](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)とさして変わらなくなるから**です。

もし許容したら、[android-studio](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio)を使って次のような質問もできるようになります。

- 画像を読み込むと*****というエラーが起きる
- Androidとサーバーとの安全な通信方法

そうなると、[android](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)とさして変わりないです。

Answer (score 0):

質問文が上手く読み取れない(後述します)ですが、確かにそうですね。
実際にAndroid Studioに関係のない質問がこのタグをつけていることが多いように見受けられます。

ただ、

> プログラミングについて質問する場所

は、どうかな？と思います。
プログラミングが指す意味合いとして実際のコーディングを指すのであればその通りですが、
SOに必要か意義を唱えているのであれば違うと考えます。

例えば、現在のSDKのインストールはAndroidStudioを通して行うことが多く
署名やNDKなどの関係もありコマンドラインよりのビルドはAndroidStudioの設定に起因する問題も起きます。
このタグが必要か不必要かの議論は主題と逸れますが、必要かと思います。
要は使い方の問題ですね。

Comment: トピックの表記が修正されてますね。そもそも修正前のをみても「SOに必要でない」とは読み取れなかったのですが……。(ニュアンスの微妙な感じでしたが。)

Comment: ”場所”というニュアンスが投稿する場所（日本語SO）を指す印象を受けていました。

Comment: やっぱり… 少しわかりにくかったですね。